# where does the wimshurst get its charges?

Tags: electricity, atmospheric-science

so i've stumbled upon the wimshurst machine, its quite a fascinating piece of equipment, although only useful in display situations only... BUT that still doesn't stop me from trying to understand it...

i realize there are numerous ways of getting static electricity.... i know the van de graff generator is based on rubber being rubbed to produce static electricity... i know you can rub a pvc pipe with fur to produce static... but how in the world does a wimshurst machine get its charges? if i'm not mistaken, the conductive plates aren't even facing each other, let alone the plastic plates that the conductive plates are attached to aren't even rubbed (it could even be glass as well).... so how in the world is it getting its charges?

i've read a article claiming that it's utilizing principles of electrostatic induction... but doesn't that require something to be charged already first, THEN it can be passed onto another object... but the conductive plates on the wimshurst isn't even charged manually.... and yet its still producing charges.... this is so fascinating to me... anyone?

Comment: While many part of the internet are forgiving of bad punctuation and capitalization, most Stack Exchange sites (definitely including [physics.se]) expect you to at least try to write well. This is really awful.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88490/

Comment: how does kelvin water experiment explain static charges of conductive plates from air, which aren't fluids? at least attempt to leave me a hook if your going to throw a jab, otherwise you've wasted everyone's time, this is also embarrassing its coming from a moderator as well.

also its 'While many part(s) of the internet are forgiving of bad punctuation(s) and capitalization(s).' btw

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wimshurst_machine

Answer (score 0):

A whistle functions like this: the oscillation starts because of noise, and builds.   Every note on a flute is born of random input.

In a Wimshurst machine, the charge transfer starts because of negligible amounts of stray charge, and builds up (there's usually a spark gap
attached, so the buildup has a limit that doesn't involve shocking the guy turning the crank).